# SDL2 Msys2 Windows X64 build

Tags: c++, c, windows, sdl-2, msys2

Trying to build SDL2-2.0.14 on Windows with latest MSYS.

If i try to build with the minimal makefile in the root SDL directory i get the following error:

```
cc -g -O2 -I./include   -c -o src/timer/dummy/SDL_systimer.o src/timer/dummy/SDL_systimer.c
cc -g -O2 -I./include   -c -o src/video/SDL_RLEaccel.o src/video/SDL_RLEaccel.c
cc -g -O2 -I./include   -c -o src/video/SDL_blit.o src/video/SDL_blit.c
cc -g -O2 -I./include   -c -o src/video/SDL_blit_0.o src/video/SDL_blit_0.c
cc -g -O2 -I./include   -c -o src/video/SDL_blit_1.o src/video/SDL_blit_1.c
cc -g -O2 -I./include   -c -o src/video/SDL_blit_A.o src/video/SDL_blit_A.c
cc -g -O2 -I./include   -c -o src/video/SDL_blit_N.o src/video/SDL_blit_N.c
cc -g -O2 -I./include   -c -o src/video/SDL_blit_auto.o src/video/SDL_blit_auto.c
cc -g -O2 -I./include   -c -o src/video/SDL_blit_copy.o src/video/SDL_blit_copy.c
cc -g -O2 -I./include   -c -o src/video/SDL_blit_slow.o src/video/SDL_blit_slow.c
cc -g -O2 -I./include   -c -o src/video/SDL_bmp.o src/video/SDL_bmp.c
cc -g -O2 -I./include   -c -o src/video/SDL_clipboard.o src/video/SDL_clipboard.c
cc -g -O2 -I./include   -c -o src/video/SDL_egl.o src/video/SDL_egl.c
src/video/SDL_egl.c:25:2: error: #error this should be not defined
   25 | #error this should be not defined
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from src/video/SDL_egl_c.h:28,
                 from src/video/SDL_egl.c:36:
./include/SDL_egl.h:29:10: fatal error: EGL/egl.h: No such file or directory
   29 | #include <EGL/egl.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: src/video/SDL_egl.o] Error 1
```

Solved it removing OPENGL support in include/SDL_config_windows.h:269:

```
#ifndef SDL_VIDEO_OPENGL_EGL
/* #define SDL_VIDEO_OPENGL_EGL    1  commented for wind64 build */
#endif
```

Now i've got the libSDL.a file, but if i try to build a test from the test folder:

```
Alessandro@DESKTOP-954PK5R MINGW64 /c/WORK/sdl_latest/SDL2-2.0.14/test
$ cc -g testkeys.c ../libSDL.a -I../include -o testkeys.exe
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\tmp\ccSosm3W.o: in function `SDL_main':
C:\WORK\sdl_latest\SDL2-2.0.14\test/testkeys.c:28: undefined reference to `SDL_LogSetPriority'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\WORK\sdl_latest\SDL2-2.0.14\test/testkeys.c:30: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\WORK\sdl_latest\SDL2-2.0.14\test/testkeys.c:31: undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\WORK\sdl_latest\SDL2-2.0.14\test/testkeys.c:31: undefined reference to `SDL_LogError'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\WORK\sdl_latest\SDL2-2.0.14\test/testkeys.c:35: undefined reference to `SDL_GetScancodeName'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\WORK\sdl_latest\SDL2-2.0.14\test/testkeys.c:35: undefined reference to `SDL_Log'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\WORK\sdl_latest\SDL2-2.0.14\test/testkeys.c:38: undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o): in function `main':
C:/_/M/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Do i have to link something else?

Comment: Why not install a prebuilt package with `pacman` ?

Comment: I want to eventually build SDL in my application executable

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I just want to compile SDL's C code directly as part of my project, i want to statically link SDL in my application.

Comment: But the SDL package (as well as the official site) already offers a prebuilt static library, which you can statically link.

Comment: Didn't actually build the code but i've understood that the Makefile has to be modified to compile sections of code as user demands. The video section of SDL, as example, can be implemented with several different libraries, from which the user can choose.